# Implement trait for trait with static function

Tags: rust

```
trait Trait<T> {
    fn equality() -> bool;
}

impl<T> PartialEq for Trait<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Trait<T>) -> bool {
        self.equality()
    }
}
```

Results in

```
main.rs:5:23: 5:31 error: the trait `Trait` cannot be made into an object [E0372]
main.rs:5 impl<T> PartialEq for Trait<T> {
```

Removing the static method makes it compilable. Methods with &self parameter compile, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes down to a matter known as *object safety*, which you can find information of in [RFC 255](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0255-object-safety.md); Huon has [a good explanation of object safety in his blog](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/), too.

Basically, making a trait object requires an implied definition of the trait for its own trait object; in this case, that would be `impl<'a, T> Trait<T> for Trait<T> + 'a`. If it is possible to write meaningful definitions of all the methods, then a trait is object safe. Static methods don’t make sense in this context—what would the body of `fn equality() -> bool` be, with no `Self` type around to call the `equality` method on? It would need to pull a boolean out of thin air, which it respectfully declines to do.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Chris' answer, what you probably want is `fn equality(&self) -> bool`. `fn equality() -> bool` is a static method, also known as an associated function. It is called as `Trait::equality()`, not `obj.equality()`, and can't access the fields and methods of the object it is called on.

Comment: Yes, I knew that already. The static method was originally called new, so staticness was required.